# Android Speech recognition and Unity: skipped frames

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, speech-recognition

I built an Android .aar file to handle the Speech Recognition workflow to use in Unity's applications.

**Android's**

The problem is: SpeechRecognition's methods want to be called inside the UI Thread. But doing this, I get the messages *"Too much work in UI Thread: Skipped 60 frames"*. I can't call the SpeechRecognition's in an other thread because I would get the message *"SpeechRecognition should run in UI Thread"*.

This is the typical workflow, the same that can be found in internet:

```
CreateSpeechListener()
SpeechRecognizer rec = SpeechRecognizer.CreateSpeechRecognizer();
rec.CreateIntent, rec.AssignSpeechListener, rec.StartListening
//
OnResult():
GetWords
ProcessWords
rec.CreateIntent, rec.StartListening
//
OnError()
if(!NETWORK_ERRROR)
    print(error), rec.CreateIntent, rec.StartListening
//
StopRecognizer()
rec.StopListening.Cancel.Destroy
```

I wrote in "pseudo-code" because as I said is the same one which can be found, but if it's necessary I will put the whole code.

**From Android to Unity**

Still, in Unity's Android application I used to get the message *"SpeechRecognition should run in UI Thread"*; so, I had to create 2 Runnables, StartRec and StopRec, and run them in the the Unity's application Activity with `runInUiThread()`. Without doing this, Unity was complaining.

```
public class StartRecognition implements Runnable {

    // Class which implmentes the workflow written above
    private RecognizerFactory r; 

    public StartRecognition(RecognizerFactory rec){
        this.r = rec;
    }

    public void run(){

        r.createRecognizer();
        r.listen();
        return;
    }
}


public class StopRecognition implements Runnable {

    private RecognizerFactory r;

    public StopRecognition(RecognizerFactory rec){
        this.r = rec;
    }

    public void run(){

        r.stopRecognizer();
        return;
    }
}
```

**Unity's**

In Unity, I create the *Recognizerfactory* rec and the 2 Runnables, start_rec and stop_rec, passing rec to both. Finally I call RunInUiThread():

```
if(*some input*)
UnityActivity.Call("runInUiThread", start_rec);

if(*other input*)
UnityActivity.Call("runInUiThread", stop_rec);
```

**The Question**

I hope I was clear! The question is: is this a right workflow? Are they common issues?
Because regarding the skipped frames an obvious solution is to use other threads but with Speechrecognition this is not possible and I couldn't find common issues.

Thank to everyone

Comment: You have too much work due to some other code it seems, not due to recognizer. Try to disable processing of speech recognition results and see if it works without delays. Then try to put `ProcessWords` in a separate thread.

Comment: ProcessWord just call a method defined in a public interface. The implementation of this interface is done in Unity (so then I can use this API defining in Unity the action I wish).
It's working, I am just wondering if this frame skipping is normal.

Comment: No, it is not a good practice to write code which leads to frame skipping. It means your UI is not responsive enough.